# Create xgboost Dmatrix in c++

Tags: c++, xgboost

I'd like to use xgboost for image classification in c++ project. I have matrix of features (hist) cv::Mat_ and vector of labels, std::vector, how can I create xgboost::DMatrix in c++? I think I should use DMatrix::Create(), but I don't understand which parameters I should pass.

```
std::vector<int> labels; //read this labels from csv
auto features = extract_features(img_ident, dir); 
cv::Mat_<float> training_set(features);

xgboost::DMatrix xgb_data = xgboost::DMatrix::Create(????);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the c_api:

```
DMatrixHandle xgbData;
int success = XGDMatrixCreateFromMat(&features[0], m_nRowCount, m_nColCount, 0, &xgbData);
if(success != 0)
  THROW_ERROR("Error creating DMatrix\n");

success = XGDMatrixSetFloatInfo(xgbData, "label", &matrixYLabels[0], m_nRowCount);
if(success != 0)
  THROW_ERROR("Error setting Y values in DMatrix\n");

success = XGDMatrixSaveBinary(xgbData, filename, false);
if(success != 0)
  THROW_ERROR("Error saving DMatrix\n");
```